# Problemas con flutter web

Tags: flutter

alguna persona de aquí a desarrollado un sistema usando flutter en su versión web, lo que pasa es que estoy creando una platilla con varios widget y en el navegador del pc corre de manera rápida y en pwa en algunos dispositivos móviles se llega a sentir que baja muchísimo el rendimiento, es normal esto?, la verdad es que con probé otras web's y funcionan muy rápido pero solo utilizan contenedores y nada mas, en cambio yo tengo muchos varios widget, es posible que eso sea el problema? solo utilizo widgets que vienen por defecto.